# Finding Json string in .NET Request object

Tags: asp.net, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve JSON via ASP.Net context.Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398926/how-to-retrieve-json-via-asp-net-context-request)

Im trying to parse an Json object but i dont understand where in the context.Request object i can find the actual data (in string format i guess).

This is how i pass the Json data to the server

```
$(function () {
    // Do your stuff here

    alert("wööööö");

    urlToHandler = 'JSonTestHandler.ashx';
    jsonData = '{ "FavoriteFood":"Pasta with butter and cheese", "FavoriteSport": "Submission Wrestling", "FavoriteGame": "Starcraft 2", "FavoriteMusic": "Hip Hop" }';
    $.ajax({
        url: urlToHandler,
        data: jsonData,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            setAutocompleteData(data.responseDateTime);
        },
        error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert('There was an error.');
        }
    }); // end $.ajax


});
```

Comment: What kind of asp is it mvc or old school

Comment: How are you passing the JSON object to your server side?

Comment: @Bardo I added the information to the question.

Comment: Also asked again here by same user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515426/post-json-data-to-net-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string jsonInput=  new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: The Request.Params has a lot of values but no jsonData.

Comment: I have changed my answer from Request.Params["jsonData"] to above. Please check